# How to interpret color gradients in Redmine roadmap?

Tags: redmine

How does one interpret the color gradients in a [Redmine roadmap](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRoadmap)? The documentation only has a rather terse description:

> a progress bar which indicates overall active/done/closed-ratio based
>   on the %-done, estimated time and statuses of the issues targeted to
>   the corresponding version, visualized by different color gradients

I have a project with one version, two features, and some open and closed issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So I've found out the answer from inspecting Redmine's HTML source code and CSS stylesheet.

I was under the impression there could be arbitrarily many color gradients, but in fact Redmine seems to use only three in this progress bar: dark blue, light blue, and light gray correspond to percentages of *closed*, *done*, and *todo* items respectively. The percentage shown to the right of the progress bar equals *closed + done*.